# Google ads not displaying on main page : asp.net

Tags: asp.net, adsense, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

**Problem**

My webpage [Here](http://fatehjangcity.com) not displaying google ads, as website is asp.net web application.

The first step i did was to observe the problem and what i observed is that when i use proxy(i.e:germany:zenmate), ad displays, so i figured it out that it could be the keywords issue.

But when i appended the '/' at the end of that url, ad displayed but not for long.

I think its a common problem due to insufficient google adbot's keywords but i am confused here because my main page dosent's seems like it has keyword issue.
(also tested with chrome_console)

! : I am facing this problem as google ads not displaying on my website's index page which is 'default' by default.

**Question**

My question is, how can i check or debug the problem if its keywords issue.

**Ad Script**

```
<div class="tag-box tag-box-v4">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- AdUnit339 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6388320024432940"
     data-ad-slot="8541014551"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

If someone has knowledge about that problem please do help.thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Adsense will stop serving ads when there are a certain number of hits from one IP. So, if you are testing your website for displaying ads, it wil stop showing ads at some point.